# JavaFX Chart: Dynamic data causes visual axis glitches when animation is enabled

Tags: animation, javafx, charts

[Application with visual glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXHjE.png)

[Application without visual glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ5gk.png)

Whenever I have a chart that has dynamically updating data and I leave chart.setAnimated(true) as it is, the axis will visually glitch every now and again as shown on the screenshots.

Is it at all possible to prevent this while keeping animation enabled?

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;

public class SavingsCalculatorApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        
        LineChart chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 10);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setPadding(new Insets(20, 40, 0, 40));
        
        XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();
        chart.getData().add(data);
        
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(event -> {
            data.getData().clear();
            for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
                data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(counter, counter * slider.getValue()));
            }
        });
        
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().add(slider);
        layout.getChildren().add(chart);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(SavingsCalculatorApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a bug: somehow the axis seem to not be completely updated - no idea how to hack around ..